Relationship between roots of the cubic polynomials $x^3-x^2-1$
The roots of the polynomials $x^3-x^2-1$ are given by $\alpha = a+b+c, \beta = a+b\omega+c\omega^2, \gamma = \bar{\beta} = a+b\omega^2+c\omega$ where $a = \frac{1}{3}, b = \left(\frac{29}{54}+\sqrt{\frac{31}{108}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}, c = \left(\frac{29}{54}-\sqrt{\frac{31}{108}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}.$ I am trying to find out the relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta.$ It is there in a literature that if $\mu$ is the real root and $\nu$ and $\eta$ are the complex roots of $x^3-x^2-x-1.$ Then $\nu = \alpha^{-1/2}e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta \in (\pi/2,\pi).$ Can we similarly find such relation?

Here, we can write:
$$\alpha\beta\gamma=1$$
and again:
$$\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=0$$
$$\Rightarrow\gamma(\alpha+\beta)=-\alpha\beta$$
$$\gamma=-\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$$
And therefore:
$$\alpha^2\beta^2+(\alpha+\beta)=0$$
$$\alpha^2\beta^2+\alpha+\beta=0$$
$$\alpha=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4\beta^3}}{2}$$
The only relationship I could see here. Anything more is always appreciated.

@M. Riyan thank you.
